# Elasticsearch query_string in filter fails after upgrade to 5.6

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following Elasticsearch query (its usually bigger, but stripped out the part which causes the issues):

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [{
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "query": {
                            "query_string": {
                                "query": "notsoimportant"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

We had it working in ES 2.3.5 for months without a problem. We want to upgrade now to ES 5.6, but now this query is failing with:

```
"type": "parsing_exception",
"reason": "no [query] registered for [query]"
```

I struggle to find the breaking change notification in the docs here. Can someone a) point out the change in the docs and b) rewrite this query so it yields the same results?

ps: I found that `filtered` queries are not a thing anymore, but I see no changes regarding `query_string` and `filter` queries combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `query` inside the `must` clause. Your query needs to look like this

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [{
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "query_string": {
                            "query": "notsoimportant"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thx a lot! that fixed it! do you know where in the docs this breaking change is documented?